# .CreateField Method using a string var as the Name

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is what I have so far with some extraneous code left out and some anonymous database and variable names:

```
Dim dB as DAO.Database
Dim tdf as DAO.TableDef
Dim newField As DAO.Field

Dim newFieldNameVar As String

newFieldNameVar = "Variable Name"

Set dB = CurrentDb

Set tdf = dB.TableDefs("PreExistingTable")

Set newField = tdf.CreateField(newFieldNameVar)

tdf.Fields.Append newField

Set newField = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set dB = Nothing
```

Where the aforementioned code exists in my function is not in a loop but the newFieldNameVar is a product of a loop, and so changes regularly based on question thread irrelevant conditions.

At the point the .Fields.Append line executes I get this run-time error: Invalid field data type. '3259' I am fairly new to programming in any form or fashion, but imagine that I might be using the wrong syntax for the variable used as the Name element of the .CreateField Method. Any ideas? Am I able to use a string variable as the Name in the .CreateField Method?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: This seems like it has the potential to bloat a table rather badly.  Why do you need another column?

Comment: I am converting data and I must pull out groups of atrributes in the files I am converting (expected and unexpected) as I run my program on the dataset as a whole.  I understand the 255 field limit of a table but I need to have to ability to create new fields as my program encounters new data associated with this specific table.

Comment: Okay, so what criteria are you using to determine when new fields are needed?  Why are temp tables not an option?  Can the data be migrated?  This smells like an XY Problem; you have a solution in mind, but we don't even know the root cause this solution is supposed to resolve.

Comment: I am unsure why knowing when new fields are needed and your first response are relevant to my original question.  Am I able to use a string variable as the Name in the .CreateField Method?  If you need parameters to answer the question presume that new fields are needed when x  = 1 or when pigs fly (whatever you prefer)  Temp tables are not an option because I will need to use the data collected for future uses (making pigs fly).  The data does not need to be migrated.  The solution I have in mind is to create a new field using a variable name.  Is this possible, if not I will find a solution.

Comment: Because this is a rather dangerous way to go about it, and will lead to trouble in the future.  Which is why I'm trying to learn more about what the whole goal of this is, so we can try to solve the root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Type` is an optional parameter of the `.CreateField` method, each field *does* need a type before you can append it to the table, else Access will throw this error.

It's also a good practice to specify field size.

Specify your field type, e.g.:

```
Dim dB as DAO.Database
Dim tdf as DAO.TableDef
Dim newField As DAO.Field

Dim newFieldNameVar As String

newFieldNameVar = "Variable Name"

Set dB = CurrentDb

Set tdf = dB.TableDefs("PreExistingTable")

Set newField = tdf.CreateField(newFieldNameVar, dbText, 255) '255 character long text field

tdf.Fields.Append newField

Set newField = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set dB = Nothing
```

Comment: That was the trick.  Now i can make my pigs fly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @HarmLeastOne if the answer solved your problem, please accept it. This will help future users facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow.   The green check on the side of the answer I am assuming?

Comment: @HarmLeastOne Yes. You can read more about accepting [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), which is a useful resource for beginners.